# Database blocked and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there a possibilty to make a thread that is only for showing a progressdialog while a method is running, without putting the operation itself inside the thread, as it is done in **AsyncTask**?

Let’s say first line of method is something like `startThread` with something like `ProgDialog.show()`, last line is something like `stopThread` with something like `ProgDialog.dismiss()`.

The reason I ask for that is, that I tried it with **AsyncTask**, and it worked well until the database-method what I called inside **AsyncTask** was trying to do database operations while other database operations in main UI were not yet finished (or tried to start).

So I got an exception that the database is blocked. I most often work with transactions in sqlite for consistency and performance, which is also necessary in this case.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html here. you should synchronize your methods perhaps. There're could be something wrong with an architecture. The locks are normal the deadlocks are not normal.

Comment: best way is to have a single database manager class which executes all db operations on a single thread(or at least manage multiple thread synchs)...you can use a Handler to execute all db operations in it...and the code is also safe as there is no way of creating deadlocks in future code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a possibilty to make a thread that is only for showing a progressdialog while a method is running, without putting the operation itself inside the thread, as it is done in AsyncTask? Let’s say first line of method is something like startThread with something like ProgDialog.show(), last line is something like stopThread with something like ProgDialog.dismiss().

No, because the only thread that can show and dismiss a dialog is the main application thread, and you specifically do not want to block that thread.

> It worked well until the database-method what I called inside AsyncTask was trying to do database operations while other database operations in main UI were not yet finished (or tried to start).

Move the "other database operations" off the main application thread.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I put all consequent DB-methods inside AsyncTask.